# How to archive DynamoDB records based on primary key

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to archive records from my DynamoDB table. I have a Lambda script that pushes records into the DynamoDB table from an Oracle database table. I only want to archive a record into an s3 bucket if the a record coming in from the database has a primary key that already exists in the DynamoDB table. The old the data associated with the primary key should be pushed to s3 and the new data should be loaded to the DynamoDB table.

This is my Python Lambda script. I am only loading the records that were not processed by previous lambda executions.(adding 5 seconds just to make sure)

```
from boto3 import resource, client
from cx_Oracle import connect
from logging import getLogger, DEBUG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    log_g_name = "/aws/lambda/lambda"
    
    client_log = client('logs')
    
    stream_response = client_log.describe_log_streams(logGroupName= log_g_name, orderBy='LastEventTime', limit = 1, descending=True)
    
    last_run = datetime.fromtimestamp(stream_response['logStreams'][0]['lastEventTimestamp']/1000.0) + timedelta(seconds=5)
    
    dynamodb = resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')
    
    connstr = 'conn_str'
    connection = connect(connstr)
    cur = connection.cursor()
    
    cur.execute("select * from table where timestamp >= '%s'" % last_run)
    
    columns = [column[0] for column in cur.description]
    
    results = []
    
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        
         results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    
    
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:

        for item in results:
        
            batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

Comment: (1) Use a [bind variable](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) instead of '%s'" for security and (in general) scalability. (2) [tune `arraysize`](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance) for performance.   (3) Upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle release, now called [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: @ChristopherJones I am working from windows so I had to create an EC2 instance in Linux to create the cx_oracle Lambda layer. Should I do the same with oracledb?

Comment: @ChristopherJones The AWS EC2 Instance with Amazon Linux 2 AMI comes with Python 3.7, so that is why I had to install cx_Oracle.

Comment: python-oracledb binaries exist (at time of writing) for Python 3.6 - 3.11.  Also see https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-python-oracle-connection/pull/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider enabling DynamoDB [Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on your table to capture change events.  Archiving is a common [use case](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) for Streams.

Your solution would have two Lambda functions.  The first Lambda writes the Oracle records to the DynamoDB table.

Once [enabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html#Streams.Enabling), Streams will raise events when your table is updated.  Configure a second Lambda to [consume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html#services-dynamodb-eventsourcemapping) these Stream events, writing the record to S3.  The Lambda service will invoke this function when events are available<sup>1</sup>, sending the changed record in the invocation's payload<sup>2</sup>.

You can [filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) events that your stream Lambda receives.  For your use case, seems you'd filter only on update events (`"eventName": ["MODIFY"]`), ignoring create and delete events.

---

[1] Behind the scenes, Streams sends the events to a hidden, AWS-managed queue, which the Lambda service periodically polls.

[2] The paylaod is configurable. For your case, you need the `OLD_IMAGE`, that is, *the entire item, as it appeared before it was modified*.

Comment: Could you provide me a sample python script that consumes these stream events?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and set the `StreamViewType` to be `OLD_IMAGE` which will make DynamoDB stream the data you want.  (New records will not have `OLD_IMAGE`, only updated and deleted ones.)

If your scale justifies, you can send this stream, to Kinesis Data Streams and from there to Kinesis Data Firehose, which will pack your data into S3.  This is minimum effort, highest throughput, highest cost solution.

If your volume does not justify that, you can create a Lambda to be triggered by the DynamoDB stream; this Lambda can then write the batches it receives into S3.